# R drawing 2 lines with confidence interval on the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, linegraph

I am trying to draw two lines on the same graph with odds ratio and confidence interval. X axis is age group and y axis is odds ratio. There are two groups: cases and control

This is what I tried so far

```
age_group <- c("18-30", "30-45", "45-60", "60-75", "75-90", "90+")

df_hosp_adm_can <- data.frame(
  age_group = 1:length(age_group),
  Number_of_hospitalisation = c(3.1, 11.9, 9.6, 9, 93, 8.9),
  range_days = c(4.3, 19.6, 29.5, 24.3, 25.3, 25.2)
)

df_hosp_adm_non_can <- data.frame(
  age_group = 1:length(age_group),
  Number_of_hospitalisation =
    c(3.1, 3.2, 2.5, 3.3, 4.8, 5.0),
  range_days =
    c(5.8, 10.9, 14.6, 16.1, 21.2, 14.3)
)

hosp_adm <- df_hosp_adm_can %>%
  mutate(Group = "Case") %>%
  bind_rows(df_hosp_adm_non_can %>% mutate(Group = "Control")) %>%
  mutate(Group = Group %>% fct_inorder())

hosp_adm %>% ggplot(aes(age_group, Number_of_hospitalisation,
  fill = Group, color = Group
)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(
    ymin = Number_of_hospitalisation - range_days,
    ymax = Number_of_hospitalisation + range_days, color = NULL
  ), alpha = 0.2)
```

This produces this graph with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 as x axis instead of the age group. When I try to change the code to this for both dataframes:

```
df_hosp_adm_non_can <- data.frame(age_group), 
                              Number_of_hospitalisation = 
       c(3.1,3.2,2.5,3.3,4.8,5.0), 
                              range_days = 
      c(5.8,10.9,14.6,16.1,21.2,14.3)
)
```

I get the error "aes is missing". What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.frame(age_group, ...)` is the way to go. But in that case you have to add the `group` aesthetic, i.e. add `group = Group` as `age_group` is a discrete or categorical variable (Perhaps that's what you meant by "aes is missing"?):

```r
library(tidyverse)

age_group <- c("18-30", "30-45", "45-60", "60-75", "75-90", "90+")

df_hosp_adm_can <- data.frame(
  age_group,
  Number_of_hospitalisation = c(3.1, 11.9, 9.6, 9, 93, 8.9),
  range_days = c(4.3, 19.6, 29.5, 24.3, 25.3, 25.2)
)

df_hosp_adm_non_can <- data.frame(
  age_group,
  Number_of_hospitalisation = c(3.1, 3.2, 2.5, 3.3, 4.8, 5.0),
  range_days = c(5.8, 10.9, 14.6, 16.1, 21.2, 14.3)
)

hosp_adm <- list(
  Case = df_hosp_adm_can,
  Control = df_hosp_adm_non_can
) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "Group") |>
  mutate(Group = fct_inorder(Group))

hosp_adm %>%
  ggplot(aes(age_group, Number_of_hospitalisation,
    fill = Group, color = Group, group = Group
  )) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(
    ymin = Number_of_hospitalisation - range_days,
    ymax = Number_of_hospitalisation + range_days, color = NULL
  ), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly now. If I wanted to add multiple lines onto this graph to reflect other groups, do I just add more dfs to this?
hosp_adm <- list(
  Case = df_hosp_adm_can,
  Control = df_hosp_adm_non_can
) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "Group") |>
  mutate(Group = fct_inorder(Group))

Comment: Yep. You can add more dfs to the `list()`, i.e. there is not need to add an identifier manually using `mutate` as you did in your code. (: And probably this could simplified even further by storing your dfs in a list when importing the data instead of creating separate dfs. But that's a different matter.

Comment: That's a good point, I could just create a separate dfs with the data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am trying to do the same as above but for multiple groups. Here is my data: